# Group one or more matching items while iterating through in a list

Tags: java, java-7

If I need to iterate over a list and try to group elements together, what is the best way to go about this?

Let's say for example we have the following objects to loop through:

```
People
  |---Person
  |     -FirstName: Jimmy
  |     -LastName: Ward
  |     -Address1: 1 Main Street
  |     -Town: Yipee
  |     -Country: Canada
  |     -Postcode: ABC
  |---Person
  |     -FirstName: Johnny
  |     -LastName: Jones
  |     -Address1: 21 Jump Street
  |     -Town: SomeTownie
  |     -Country: Ireland
  |     -Postcode: ZZZ
  |---Person
  |     -FirstName: Vinny
  |     -LastName: McWhinney
  |     -Address1: 11 Blah Lane 
  |     -Town: Pastaville
  |     -Country: Italy
  |     -Postcode: ALO
  |---Person
  |     -FirstName: Tommy
  |     -LastName: Jones
  |     -Address1: 21 Jump Street
  |     -Town: SomeTownie
  |     -Country: Ireland
  |     -Postcode: ZZZ
  |---Person
  |     -FirstName: Wendy
  |     -LastName: Ward
  |     -Address1: 1 Main Street
  |     -Town: Yipee
  |     -Country: Canada
  |     -Postcode: ABC
  |---Person
  |     -FirstName: Jenny
  |     -LastName: Bloggs
  |     -Address1: 1 Yadda Road
  |     -Town: Blahdeblah
  |     -Country: Ireland
  |     -Postcode: XYZ
```

I need to go through each person, and create a group with people with the same address and same lastname.

For example, it starts with Jimmy, iterates through the list to find anyone with the same address and lastname, only Wendy matches so they both get grouped together. Next is Johnny, and Tommy is the only match.

When iterating through the remaining people in the list, we do not want to go through the same process for Wendy or Tommy (as they have already been grouped). So we need to remove those that have been matched from the original list, or insert into a map somehow?

I was thinking a while loop, and then for loop to find any matches. Disclaimer: this proposed solution for removing those matching, so could be way off the mark.

For example:

```
while (!originalPersonList.isEmpty()) {
  ArrayList<Person> newGroup = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<Integer> indexToRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  newGroup.add(0);
  indexToRemove.add(0);
  for (int i=1; i < originalPersonList.size(); i++) {
    if (originalPersonList.get(0).Address1().equals( originalPersonList.get(i).Address1())
      && originalPersonList.get(0).Town().equals(originalPersonList.get(i).Town())
      && originalPersonList.get(0).Country().equals( originalPersonList.get(i).Country())
      && originalPersonList.get(0).Postcode().equals( originalPersonList.get(i).Postcode()
      && originalPersonList.get(0).Lastname().equals( originalPersonList.get(i).Lastname()) 
    {
       indexToRemove.add(i);
       newGroup.add(i);
    }
  }
  originalPersonList.removeAll(indexToRemove);
}
```

This was the direction I was going towards, but I feel there might be a more elegant solution out there?

I'm restricted to using Java7.

Also I tried searching for similar questions, and there wasn't any matching this particular scenario.

Comment: Have you thought about using a Map? The key could be the address and the value a collection of objects that share the same address.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón thanks for the suggestion. I'd be interested in learning more. It's not just address that is being checked though, it is other fields like Lastname. How would a key work in that scenario - would it still be considered 'clean' to have a key with that many field values associated to it?

Comment: I forgot about the lastname, but I believe having a class that represents this key is a valid approach. I would even say it would be advisable because this set of fields probably represent a concept that is worth to encapsulate (same address and lastname sounds like a family). Just keep in mind that this key class would have to implement equals() and hashCode() (this two methods should be consistent) to be able to be used in comparisons and hash maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HernánAlarcón said, Map is a good use case scenario for what you ask. So let's go step by step:

**Creating the Person POJO**

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String town;
    private String country;
    private String postCode;

//Constructor,Getters,Setters ommited for clarity
}
```

Maps need a class for a key that has a proper hashcode/equals implementation. So let's create a class which contains the criteria you want:

**PersonProjection**

```
public class PersonProjection {
    private String lastname;
    private String address;

    public PersonProjection(String lastname, String address) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PersonProjection that = (PersonProjection) o;
        return Objects.equals(lastname, that.lastname) &&
                Objects.equals(address, that.address);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(lastname, address);
    }
}
```

Below is the main code which is Java 7 compatible if not mistaken (8+ makes things simpler than that):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create map
    Map<PersonProjection, List<Person>> map = new HashMap<>();

    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

    //...Fill list

    for(Person p : personList)
    {
        //Create the projection
        PersonProjection projection = new PersonProjection(p.getLastName(),p.getAddress());

        //Initialize an arraylist whenever a new key is going to be inserted
        if(!map.containsKey(projection))
            map.put(projection,new ArrayList<Person>());

        //Put the person in the corresponding arraylist
        map.get(projection).add(p);
    }
}
```

Please note that this code is untested.

Comment: I've marked this as answered. Definitely cleaner than how I was approaching it. Thanks both for the answer, and @NickDelta for the code example - this is much easier to understand.

Comment: @n1234 Glad I helped !

Comment: Just one question about this solution... what happens with a field being null. Can another person with the same field being null match against it? Doesn't feel correct that it would potentially match with someone just because of missing data. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Another person with exactly the same 2 fields will match against it. For example, a person named John Doe who doesn't have an address (null)  will match against all those whose last name is Doe and don't have an address (e.g Nick Doe,null). If you don't want this behavior then you must make adjustments to the equals/hashcode implementation of PersonProjection

Comment: Is there any way to have the solution work so it only matches against fields with a non-null value? I take it that's where the .equals() will help fix that?

Comment: Playing around with equals can break the contract between it and hashcode and produce some very unexpected results. Although you can play dirty with it, on second thoughts, I see this issue as something that must be handled without touching them. Maybe ignoring persons that have null attributes while iterating ?